# Java: Type of iterator in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>> result = new ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>>();

    for(LinkedList<TreeNode> entry : result)
```

Why in for loop result is `LinkedList<TreeNode>` and not `ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>>`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The type of `result` is `ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>>`.  The type of **`entry`** is `LinkedList<TreeNode>`.

Comment: It's obvious from the loop, LinkedList<TreeNode> entry means that entry is a LinkedList<TreeNode>. What do you expect?

Comment: oh okay. Actually I am new to Java so learning. Thanks got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `ArrayList` of `LinkedList`s, so each element of your `ArrayList` is a `LinkedList`. This is what you wrote in your for loop: you are iterating over elements of ArrayList, i.e. over `LinkedList`s.

And BTW, avoid writing concrete classes at the left side of assignment, i.e.

`ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>> result = new ArrayList<LinkedList<TreeNode>>();`
should be written as

`List<List<TreeNode>> result = new ArrayList<List<TreeNode>>();`

now you can say:

`for(List<TreeNode> entry : result)`

It is more flexible because you can change your implementation without changing any other code.

Answer (score 1):

Because the foreach loop type is of the type the collection contains.
The collection: `result` is an `ArrayList`.
It contains objects of type `LinkedList<TreeNode>`.
Thus that is the type inside the collection `result`, which you use in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
for(LinkedList<TreeNode> entry : result)
```

would be read in English as "For every `LinkedList<TreeNode>` in `result`, do ...". The variable `entry` is set to each `LinkedList<TreeNode>` from the `ArrayList`, one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The type of element in the for each loop is the one contains in the list so it's `<LinkedList<TreeNode>`. You retrieve the element in the list not a part of the list or something...